# c++: private inheritance ambiguous call

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

In the code below the public method `Base2::f()` is expected to become a private member of the `Derived` class however the compiler complains about ambiguity.

The question is on the basic understanding of inheritance. I appreciate if someone can help to shed some light on it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename TDerived>
class Base1 {
 public:
  void f() { static_cast<TDerived &>(*this)->f_impl(); }
};

class Base2 {
 public:
  void f() { std::cout << "f()" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base1<Derived>, private Base2 {
 public:
  void f_impl() { std::cout << "f_impl()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  Derived d;

  d.f();
}
```

Comment: If we call `d.f()` do we call `Base1::f()` or `Base2::f()` ?

Comment: My understanding is that `Base2::f()` is out of scope as it does not belong to a public interface of `Derived` due to private inheritance

Comment: The check of visibility (public/private) is done **after** the selection, and so it is ambiguous

Comment: @Jarod42 One learns something every day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) rightfully posted the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67213877/c-private-inheritance-ambiguous-call#comment118805465_67213877)

> The check of visibility (public/private) is done after the selection,
> and so it is ambiguous

Here is a relevant section from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)

> Member access does not affect visibility: names of private and
> privately-inherited members are visible and considered by overload
> resolution, implicit conversions to inaccessible base classes are
> still considered, etc. Member access check is the last step after any
> given language construct is interpreted. The intent of this rule is
> that replacing any private with public never alters the behavior of
> the program.